# Get user object from socket.io when authenticating with http-auth

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, http-authentication

I want to get the user object when a socket.io connection is established. This way I can log the actions of the user.

With express.js I can get the user like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // req.user
})
```

How can I get the user from a socket.io connection? My socket.io implementation uses the same http server as express.js.

Here is the code:

```
var auth = require('http-auth')
var basic = auth.basic({
    file: __dirname + '/.htpasswd'
})

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(basic, app)

var io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // how to get user?
})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you are missing realm option in basic authentication config.

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = require('request');
request('/users', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

     var users = body.users;
     io.on('connection', function(socket) {
           // IO EMIT USERS
     }
  }
})
```

OR ...

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  var request = require('request');
  request('/users', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

     var users = body.users;
           // IO EMIT USERS
     }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The socket.io communication is not authenticated automatically by `http-auth`. You have to authenticate the socket.io yourself.

To do so, you can reuse the internal function `isAuthenticated(req, callback)` from `http-auth` and implement it as a socket.io middleware using `io.use()`:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    // The first argument of 'isAuthenticated()' expects the http 'request' object.
    // It needs it to access the 'headers' object (request.headers)
    // We can also find the 'headers' object in 'socket.handshake', so we pass that.
    //
    // source of 'isAuthenticated()':
    // https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth/blob/c7e078ad1d7d0def72ed198860d6352f262b90e6/src/auth/base.js#L82
    basic.isAuthenticated(socket.handshake, result => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            next(result);
        } else if (!result.pass) {
            next(new Error('Authentication error'));
        } else {
            socket.user = result.user; // make sure you can access the user later
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

You can then later access the user with:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.user);
});
```